# how to add dynamic button in repeater and text should follow the id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I want to add a dynamic button control inside repeater and I want to change the text of that button which means (**If I have 2 items inside repeater than the button's text should follow the id of particular item**)

e.g. First row id is 1 then the button text should be **"button_1"**  and 
     second row id is 2 then button it's text should be **"button_2"**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the DataSource of your repeated object has an "Id" property (and we want to display it in button text), you can write it like this :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repTest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id", "button_{0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```